# Looping through API Results from Flickr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, recursion, flickr

I am really struggling to get this working.

I am querying the Flickr API which has returned me a set of arrays and hashes I can loop through to add data to my application.

I have started to write some code to iterate over the API result to create Collections. It keeps failing though and wondered if any of you guys could see if I am going about this the right way or spot what I am doing wrong:

```
  def self.add_collection(collection)
    puts "Adding collection..."
    Collection.create!({
        :flickr_id    =>  collection['id'],
        :title        =>  collection['title'],
        :description  =>  collection['description']
      })
    puts "Added collection."
  end


  def self.add_all
    tree = Flickr.collections_list
    pp tree
    puts "Got response from Flickr"
    tree.each do |c|
      c[1].each do |c|
        add_collection(c)
        if c["collection"]
          add_collection(c['collection'][0])
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

My API result is:

```
{"collections"=>
  {"collection"=>
    [{"id"=>"57928212-7215447632914033423",
      "title"=>"site.co.uk",
      "description"=>"",
      "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
      "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
      "collection"=>
       [{"id"=>"57928212-721457634949706778",
         "title"=>"Holidays",
         "description"=>"",
         "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
         "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
         "collection"=>
          [{"id"=>"57928212-724157634943457291",
            "title"=>"Standard",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576289846181735",
               "title"=>"Di-ip",
               "description"=>"11th-13th May 2008 - (-W)"},
              {"id"=>"7215-90497324306",
               "title"=>"O-ay",
               "description"=>
                "August 2005 - (P- T)"},
              {"id"=>"721576290947297760",
               "title"=>"Iceland Holiday",
               "description"=>
                "5- 2004 - (N-)"}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-742157629691182748",
            "title"=>"1 - W-09",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576296835355462",
               "title"=>"D-er",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576294683541696",
               "title"=>"D-rea",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576296843554852",
               "title"=>"D-gdom",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576297104465912",
               "title"=>"Day 4 - Gilr-walk",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576294710474644",
               "title"=>
                "Day 5 - Calif-uth",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576249710489442",
               "title"=>"Day 6 - Si-untain",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576429834618028",
               "title"=>
                "Day 7 - Unive-za",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576249834637138",
               "title"=>"Day 8 - Se-Park",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576249836419418",
               "title"=>"Day 9 - Lego-Park",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576249851123596",
               "title"=>"Day 10 - Kn-re City",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576298541700916",
               "title"=>"Day 11 & 12 - Disn-sort",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576249851713058",
               "title"=>"Day 13,14 & 15 - La-as",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721547629866347760",
            "title"=>"2 - Mi-10",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576294866337538",
               "title"=>"Day 0 - Arr-rica",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576298468655454",
               "title"=>"Day 1 - M-a",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576299707347598",
               "title"=>"Day 2 - Adven-n",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576430011649024",
               "title"=>"Day 3 - W-un",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576304034790528",
               "title"=>"Day 4 - Sil-",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576300354520246",
               "title"=>"Day 5 - St-eum",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576300443090072",
               "title"=>"Day 6 - Si-uis",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576300443098290",
               "title"=>"Day 7 - Ho-rld",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576300448416804",
               "title"=>"Day 8 - Indi-ach",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576300448431390",
               "title"=>"Day 9 - -ca",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721457629997482351",
               "title"=>
                "Day 10 - Mount O-eads",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576304059600702",
               "title"=>"Day 11 - Vall-",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721457630658165668",
            "title"=>"3 - Intim-010",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576341693409808",
               "title"=>
                "Day 1 - Gre-n City",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576306547898798",
               "title"=>"Day 1 - C-s",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576306924436584",
               "title"=>"Day 2 - -d",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721547630699845912",
               "title"=>"Day 3 - Ran-vities",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576304714758818",
               "title"=>"Day 4 - Lo-urg",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576304717785454",
               "title"=>"Day 5 - Bu-urg",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576304717785576",
               "title"=>"Day 6 - Kin-ion",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-742157631693570817",
            "title"=>"4 - Bes-12",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576316493011733",
               "title"=>
                "Day 0 - Early -orld Park",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576316934409808",
               "title"=>
                "Day 1 - Grea-ity",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576431698474564",
               "title"=>"Day 2 - Shijin-rk",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576341703216195",
               "title"=>
                "Day 3 - Happ-rk",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721574631713251068",
               "title"=>"Day 4 - Victo-g",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576314761492087",
               "title"=>"Day 5 - Floral-ark",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576318148565932",
               "title"=>"Day 6 - H-du",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576318148581382",
               "title"=>"Day -ry",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576318419272104",
               "title"=>
                "Day 8 - Ha-Park",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576314820243661",
               "title"=>
                "Day 9 - Sha-ruise",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721574631872193783",
               "title"=>
                "Day 10 - Fisherma-ervatory",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721574631874073880",
               "title"=>
                "Day 11- Gongqin-ark",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576318474794697",
               "title"=>"Day 12 - Hap-ark",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576318940558319",
               "title"=>"Day 13 - -",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319544111677",
               "title"=>
                "Day 14 - G-World",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319624210803",
               "title"=>
                "Day 15 - Chi-or",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319628749339",
               "title"=>
                "Day 16 - Kn-rld",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319751048564",
               "title"=>"Day 17 - Ha-hen",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319749243775",
               "title"=>"Day 18 - O-eing",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576319765947399",
               "title"=>"Day 19 - Dis-ong",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721576434943433385",
            "title"=>"5 - T-13",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576349908483894",
               "title"=>"Day 1 - Tai-ng",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576349954099233",
               "title"=>"Day 2 - -",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576350042484738",
               "title"=>"Day 3 - J-orld",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576350594662914",
               "title"=>
                "Day 4 - For-t",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576350545445863",
               "title"=>"Day 5-dise",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576352944144798",
               "title"=>
                "Day 6 - L-na",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721576435094962919",
            "title"=>"6 - Japan 2013",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576350944001201",
               "title"=>"Day 1 - Fli-dium",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576350494923653",
               "title"=>"Day 2 - Tok-a",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576350497502859",
               "title"=>"Day 3 - Tobu Zoo",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576351430344700",
               "title"=>"Day 4 - Uni-an",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721457635131070810",
               "title"=>"Day 5 - Hira-mple",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576351444725534",
               "title"=>"Day 6 - Yo-adise",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576351454178145",
               "title"=>"Day 7 - Nag-nd",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721547635164257344",
               "title"=>"Day 8 - Hok-oro",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576354182539619",
               "title"=>"Day 9 - Ru-ort",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576351472948421",
               "title"=>"Day 10 - Jo-ea",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576351894974362",
               "title"=>"Day 11 - -d",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576352035465038",
               "title"=>"Day 12- Tok-kitori",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576352574508275",
               "title"=>"Day 13- To-a",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576352746739360",
               "title"=>"Day 14 - Tok-ea",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576354268544001",
               "title"=>"Day 15 - --ea",
               "description"=>""}]}]},
        {"id"=>"57928212-721574628668300643",
         "title"=>"Days out",
         "description"=>"",
         "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
         "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
         "collection"=>
          [{"id"=>"57928212-721457628668352769",
            "title"=>"One off's",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576308409580828",
               "title"=>"ChThisip",
               "description"=>"Sun 29th July 2012 (Neil T, Mandy T)"},
              {"id"=>"721576306394290306",
               "title"=>"Blackpool - 8th Jul 2012",
               "description"=>
                "(Neil T, MThisS, Ben K)"},
              {"id"=>"721576299940667113",
               "title"=>
                "Legoland Thisne 2010",
               "description"=>"This)"},
              {"id"=>"721576294405676947",
               "title"=>"SkThisl 1)",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576294391564267",
               "title"=>"Canal Boating",
               "description"=>
                "SunThismas)"},
              {"id"=>"721576294391564197",
               "title"=>"SThisert",
               "description"=>
                "12th Jul 2003 - (PeThisrk T)"},
              {"id"=>"721576294391560887",
               "title"=>"BThises",
               "description"=>
                " 29thThiss A)"},
              {"id"=>"721576290848461747",
               "title"=>"Go Karting 2012",
               "description"=>" 28th Jan 2012 for Neil's birthday"},
              {"id"=>"721576349284451987",
               "title"=>
                "SThis A)",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721574628668280287",
            "title"=>"Theme Parks",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "collection"=>
             [{"id"=>"57928212-721457634949768308",
               "title"=>"TThisrk",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
               "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"721576334256718298",
                  "title"=>
                   "TThisP)",
                  "description"=>""}]},
              {"id"=>"57928212-721576429626109372",
               "title"=>"PlThisl",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
               "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"7215762945459430821",
                  "title"=>"PThis11",
                  "description"=>"(Neil T, Rick M, Jackie DM)"}]},
              {"id"=>"57928212-721576249991000745",
               "title"=>"GuThisld",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
               "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"721576296244407020",
                  "title"=>"GThis011",
                  "description"=>
                   "(NeiThiseorge)"}]},
              {"id"=>"57928212-721576294990999301",
               "title"=>"FThisd",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
               "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"721576294625410346",
                  "title"=>"FlThis0",
                  "description"=>"(NThis)"}]},
              {"id"=>"57928212-721457628668340547",
               "title"=>"DrThisor",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
               "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"721576294638932742",
                  "title"=>"DraThis010",
                  "description"=>"(NThisW)"}]},
              {"id"=>"57928212-721547628668287225",
               "title"=>"AltThisrs",
               "description"=>"",
               "iconlarge"=>
                "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7024/cols/72157628668287225_190361d603_l.jpg",
               "iconsmall"=>
                "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7024/cols/72157628668287225_190361d603_s.jpg",
               "set"=>
                [{"id"=>"721576328264334688",
                  "title"=>
                   "FebThis P)",
                  "description"=>""},
                 {"id"=>"721576306265468434",
                  "title"=>"Alt-ers - 15th Jul 2012",
                  "description"=>"(N-g A)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576303726416660",
                  "title"=>"A-n 2012",
                  "description"=>
                   "(NThis K)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576294666253333",
                  "title"=>"AThis2010",
                  "description"=>"(Thisl H)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576294990697063",
                  "title"=>"AThis10",
                  "description"=>"(This)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576299940655063",
                  "title"=>
                   "This008",
                  "description"=>"(NThis)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576429990712153",
                  "title"=>
                   "Event 2011 - 31st Oct-1st Nov 2011",
                  "description"=>"(This)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576295594429835",
                  "title"=>"This 29th-31st Oct 2009",
                  "description"=>"(ThisF)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576291947499268",
                  "title"=>
                   "Behi-l 2006",
                  "description"=>"(This)"},
                 {"id"=>"721576295411694365",
                  "title"=>"Day 2010 - 21st Jun 2010",
                  "description"=>"This)"}]}]}]},
        {"id"=>"57928212-721457628985775057",
         "title"=>"Yearly Events",
         "description"=>"",
         "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
         "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
         "collection"=>
          [{"id"=>"57928212-721576429836230144",
            "title"=>"This",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"721576299818309211",
               "title"=>"Here StThisees",
               "description"=>""},
              {"id"=>"721576296173454860",
               "title"=>"Thisats",
               "description"=>""}]},
           {"id"=>"57928212-721576258985777547",
            "title"=>"Birthdays",
            "description"=>"",
            "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
            "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
            "set"=>
             [{"id"=>"7215762899995365613",
               "title"=>"This12",
               "description"=>""}]}]},
        {"id"=>"57928212-721576298356236274",
         "title"=>"Misc",
         "description"=>"",
         "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
         "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif",
         "set"=>
          [{"id"=>"721576295511800621",
            "title"=>"This",
            "description"=>""},
           {"id"=>"721576295391565747",
            "title"=>"This",
            "description"=>""}]}]}]},
 "stat"=>"ok"}
```

I really could do with some help on this. I think it's the multi dimensional aspect of the arrays and hashes and how to create something that can loop over it to add the Collections. I need to ignore the sets for now. Sets will be added later.

UPDATE:

Been playing around with this trying to slowly figure out what each part of the hash is which and have the following:

```
  def self.add_all
    tree = Flickr.collections_list['collections']
    puts "Got response from Flickr"
    tree.each do |c|
      c.each do |d|
        ap d.class
        #add_collection(d)
      end
    end
```

When I run that, `d.class` is returning:

> String < Object
>
> Array < Object

Can can I access the Array part so I can continue iterating along as all I get told is I cannot perform .each on a String (which makes sense).

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? The approach you're going for should work, but I'm guessing there might be cases where a hash is being treated like an array or vice versa, which would cause errors. So it's really a task of verifying what kind of object you're working with at each step so that you can collect the data you're looking for.

Comment: Your API response has a parse error due to a missing `"`. Probably at:                `"description"=>This)"},`. Copy/Paste error?

Comment: Yes that was a copy paste error. Fixed now. Is there a way I can slim the API result down so I can get a clearer view of how it's hierarchy is set out so I can logically step through it?

Comment: Added update to OP. Any ideas guys? Really need to get this solved.

Comment: Be careful passing one block variable to `Hash#each`. This will yield both keys and values to your block -- probably not what you intended. To iterate over keys, use `Hash#each_key`. If you need the key-value pairs, pass two variables to `Hash#each`: `hash.each { |k, v| ... }`

Comment: This comment was very useful to me. I now understand what the output I was getting meant. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's confusing. What you need to know is

1. The array of top-level collections is at `tree["collections"]["collection"]`
2. Collections are hashes with keys for each property (`id`, `title`, `description`, etc.)
3. Collections *may* have a key named `collection` (*not* `collections`) whose value is an array of child collections

Now, given those guidelines, we can write code to traverse the tree. We call `traverse_collection` recursively to handle the child collections.

```
def traverse_collection(collection)
  Collection.create! :flickr_id => collection["id"],
    :title => collection["title"],
    :description => collection["description"]

  if collection["collection"]
    for child in collection["collection"]
      traverse_collection child
    end
  end
end

for collection in Flickr.collections_list["collections"]["collection"]
  traverse_collection collection
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Really simple and I have tried it out and tweaked it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jonahb does a splendid job of breaking down the components of the Flickr API response into manageable pieces above. Here's a slightly more Rubyesque refactoring of his code using `each` instead of `for` that matches rctneil's naming conventions.

```
def self.add_collection(collection)
  Collection.create!( flicker_id: collection['id'], 
                      title: collection['title'], 
                      description: collection['description'] )
  collection['collection'].each { |sub_collection| add_collection sub_collection } if collection['collection']
end

def self.add_all
  collections = Flickr.collections_list["collections"]["collection"]
  collections.each { |collection| add_collection collection }
end
```

One tool I find incredibly useful when working with deeply nested API responses is [Pry](http://pryrepl.org). When I'm working with a new API I'm unfamiliar with, I'll drop a `binding.pry` right after an API call and begin whittling away at it in the console. It really helps getting a solid handle on how to access what you need early on so it doesn't bog you down later when you sit down to code.

Comment: I've seen that argument a few times on Stack Overflow -- that `each` is more "Rubyesque" than `for ... in`. I must disagree. The essence of Ruby iteration, as Matz says in [this interview](http://www.artima.com/intv/closures.html), is that "the details of how to iterate should belong to the service provider class." `for ... in` and `each` both provide this encapsulation, and, in my opinion, `for ... in` is clearer and more succinct.

Comment: I won't argue with that, jonahb. Your code is certainly clear. To `each` his own, I guess? :-) Cheers!

Comment: I never knew about the for...in syntax and actually find it more readable so have used that in my code.